# React.js Error: Invariant Violation: Minified React error #37

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I've tried looking up in the internet, but I can't find the solution for this error.

Essentially, when I run my app in my localhost via `npm start`, it runs without a problem.

However, when I switch to `git branch gh-pages` to host in the gh-pages, I see the following error in my console.log

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #37

[_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=37) is what error #37 means.

[Link to Git App  Repository gh-pages branch](https://github.com/Neotriz/RecipeBox/tree/gh-pages)

Here's my current setup:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ghpages = require('gh-pages');
var WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: "./bundle.js.map",
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    },{
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      loaders: ['style','css','sass'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
    'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery'),
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    outputPath: path.join(__dirname, './dist')
  }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "recipe-box",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Portfolio",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "postinstall": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.11.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.5.0",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.16.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.7",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1 ",
    "react-materialize": "^0.16.4",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answered my own question**

It looked like I had to move `bundle.js` out from `dist` folder to the same directory where my index.html was.